# Access pointer array / through another pointer and delete single element in array without deleting first pointer or whole array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array, delete-operator

In my Main Window I create an instance of **PointerClass**, which holds an array of pointers to **PointerObject** (I want to be able to **access** it with **PointerObject[X][Y]** and **delete it the same way**, and check if **PointerObject[X][Y] == NULL** (which is **WHY** I use pointers)) and I don't want a solution with vectors.

```
#define X 10
#define Y 10

class PointerObject
{
public:
        int X;
        int Y;
}

class PointerClass
{

public:
       PointerObject       *ArrayOfPointerObjects[X][Y];
}

PointerMethod(&PointerClass);
```

Then, in my PointerMethod I create the Pointer to an array:

```
PointerMethod(PointerClass *pointerClass)
{
     // don't know the right way to do this
     pointerClass->ArrayOfPointerObjects= new PointerObject[X][Y];

     // set all pointers in the array to NULL - is this needed?
     for (int x=0; x < X; x++)
     {
         for (int y=0; y < Y; y++)
         {
              pointerClass->ArrayOfPointerObjects[x][y] = NULL;
         }
     }

     // trying to store some data here
     pointerClass->ArrayOfPointerObjects[0][0] = new PointerObject;

     // trying to delete it
     delete pointerClass->ArrayOfPointerObjects[0][0];
     // or trying this:
     delete[] pointerClass->ArrayOfPointerObjects[0][0];

     // causes access violation or doesn't work
}
```

I earlier asked this without success or questions about the wrong type.

[Delete pointer to multidimensional array in class through another pointer - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009818/delete-pointer-to-multidimensional-array-in-class-through-another-pointer-how)

I can access the array, check if it's NULL. but when I call delete / delete[] pointerClass->ArrayOfPointerObjects[x][y] it seem to delete the pointer to pointerClass instead of the element at [X][Y] and I want to delete the pointer at location [X][Y] and not the pointerClass and I don't want to delete the whole array.

How can I do this without complicating it too much? I guess my array isn't truely an array of pointers, just a pointer to an array. But I want it to be an array of pointers stored in a pointer or something. Still the importance is how I access it and how I delete the elements in the array. I need to be able to check if the pointer is NULL and if not be able to Delete that single PointerObject.

The importance of this is that I want to:

1. Access the array of PointerObjects with [X][Y]
2. Check if an object in the array is NULL (=needs pointers)
3. Delete a single item in the array of pointers without destroying the pointer to the PointerClass object or deleting the rest of the array. Just delete a single PointerObject at a certain X, Y location in the array so that [X][Y] after deletion = NULL.

If there's too much confusion or likeness with my other thread it is because people told me thing I had no wish for and it led off subject, here it is better illustrated how it works and how I want it to work like.

Comment: Your conditions in no way require "raw" pointers.

Comment: Please explain further. I can't just create a multidimensional array of PointerObjects and set PO[X][Y] = NULL, or delete PO[X][Y] or check if (PO[X][Y] == NULL) without using pointers.

Comment: `unique_ptr` for example, fulfills your requirements in full; generally I'd point you towards them and `vectors` and for some reason you seem to object such solutions.

Comment: If have requirements that prevent a solution with vectors, you need to explain why. How will people know any other solution they propose meets your undisclosed requirements?

Comment: Because of how you loop through it, because if I delete one object I have to reset the loop each time and I frequently have to delete objects, so I first check what coordinates should be deleted and then I delete them instead of looping and looping and looping.

Answer (score -1):

hmm, i think something like [this](http://ideone.com/6zJZw)

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo 
{
    int i_;
    int j_;
public:
    Foo(int i, int j) : i_(i), j_(j) {}

    void print_coords()
    {
        std::cout << this << " (" << i_ << ',' << j_ << ')' << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Foo *arr[5][5];  
};

class Que
{
public:
    void init(Bar *b)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
                b->arr[i][j] = new Foo(i, j);
    }

    void print(Bar *b, int i, int j)
    {
        try {
            if(b->arr[i][j])
                b->arr[i][j]->print_coords();
            else
               throw 0;
        } catch (int e) {
            std::cout << &b->arr[i][j] << " points to null" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void rem(Bar *b, int i, int j)
    {
        delete b->arr[i][j];
        b->arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar *b = new Bar();
    Que *q = new Que();

    q->init(b);
    q->print(b, 2, 2);
    q->rem(b, 2, 2);
    q->print(b, 2, 2);

    return 0;
}
```