# passing 2D array to another class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array

I am trying to calculate the perimeter of a rectangle. first I will prompt the user 4 times for the X and Y cords and store it into a 2D array and pass this 2D array to another class which is method class to proceed with the calculation of the perimeter. But the problem is, I don't know how to pass the 2d array to method class.

I am not asking how to calculate the perimeter, I only need to know how to pass the 2D array from main to method class and get the 2D array at method class.
Please advise.

main.cpp

```
Method method;
int main() {
   int storeXandY[4][2];
       for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
       {
           cout << "Please enter x-ordinate" << i<< endl;
           cin>>storeXandY[i][0];
           cout << "Please enter y-ordinate" << i << endl;
           cin>>storeXandY[i][1];
       }
    //how to pass the 2D array to method class to do some calculations?
    // I was thinking something like passing the 2d array to a consturctor but don't know whether it can be done
       method.constructor(storeXandY);
 }
```

method.h

```
   //not sure of what to do

public: 
    constructor() {

    }
```

method.cpp

```
    //how to get the cords from 2d array from main
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You usually want to avoid using arrays in C++, and the more dimensions they have, the more you want to avoid them. A small wrapper around a vector that overloads `operator()` to handle multi-dimension addressing is almost always easier to deal with. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009991/179910

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as :

```
class Method{
    ...
    public int calcPerimeter(int vals[4][2])
    {
       // do your calculation here using vals array
    }
    ...
}
```

From main(), you can simply do :

```
Method m = new Method();
int perimeter;
m.calcPerimeter(<your_array_name>);
```

Comment: This is sort of useful, but will almost necessarily lead to other questions: how do you use arrays with a different size? how do you store the parameter value inside an instance? how do you store a variable amount of parameters in the instance?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing C++, you should try to avoid using C-style arrays. I would do this

```
Method method;
int main() {
   vector<vector<int> > storeXandY(4);
   for(int i=0; i!=4; ++i) storeXandY[i].resize(2);

   for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
   {
       cout << "Please enter x-ordinate" << i<< endl;
       cin>>storeXandY[i-1][0]; /* you need i-1 here, not i */
       cout << "Please enter y-ordinate" << i << endl;
       cin>>storeXandY[i-1][1];
   }
   method.calcPerimeter(storeXandY);
 }
```

where `method::calcPerimeter` is declared as follows

```
your_return_type method::calcPerimeter(const vector<vector<int> >& rectangle);
```

The advantage of using vectors is that you can get the number of elements they hold by invoking their `size` member function, so that in the above code `storeXandY.size()` is equal to 4 and `storeXandY[0].size()` is equal to 2.