# declaring a multidimensional array with unknown size

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

can someone explain to me why this code doesn't work, and how can i solve it?
thank you

```
int main()
    {
    int gridSize;
    cout<<"please enter the grid size: ";
    cin>>gridSize;
    int gridArray[gridSize][gridSize];   
  }
```

Comment: In C++ you have [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Use it.

Comment: It doesn't work because C++ doesn't include VLAs. To solve it, use `std::vector` with a small wrapper to support 2D addressing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009991/179910

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg

Comment: Please get used to explaining results that you see rather than just saying "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::vector<int>(rows * cols)` or even `std::vector<std::vector<int>>()`. It doesn't work because C++ doesn't have support for VLAs. There will be `std::dynarray`s available in the upcoming technical specification.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` is the favored way to do something like that, but if you are just interested in knowing how to it manually:

```
int main()
{
    int gridSize;
    std::cout << "Enter size of grid: ";
    std::cin >> gridSize;
    int** gridArray = new int*[gridSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {   
        std::cout << std::endl << i << std::endl;
        gridArray[i] = new int[gridSize];
    }   
}
```

Basically, you are using an array of pointers to pointers, then setting up the 2nd dimension.  But if you do something like this, you would have to manually `delete` the memory to avoid leaks.  **Again, this way isn't suggested, just provided for the know-how**

[Parashift's C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/) is a great resource for any new/moderate c++ programmer.

Comment: ok thx a lot for your help, and for giving me such helpful information

Answer (score 0):

```
class Table
{
public:
    Table(int rows, int cols)
    {
        tab_.resize(rows);
        for (auto& row : tab_)
        {
            row.resize(cols);
        }
    }

    vector<int>& operator[](int row) { return tab_[row]; }
private:
    vector<vector<int> > tab_;
};
```

Comment: I would really like to understand why it has been down voted, because that's what I would do if I need a table.

Comment: 1)The OP did not ask for a table,nor a class, but simply for a dynamically sized multidimensional array.This is IMO a much to detailed solution.2)In a regular usecase I would never write a extra class for this if its not a core feature(e.g for a database lib),but operate on a vector directly in my implementation (which hides this aspect).3)If I write such a class I would design it as a template, make it support an arbitrary number of dimensions and propably implement it with a single vector or byte buffer.The main point here is simply 1):Not asked, too detailed but at the same time too general